# How to subquery - need to calculate new value based on calculated column

Tags: sql

The first query should count records - the second query needs to average the counted records. I can't figure out how to use subqueries correctly. This is what I have; obviously the "birds" column doesn't exist since it's created in the subquery, thus my outer query doesn't work:

```
SELECT
      avg(birds)
    FROM [FocalAreas].[dbo].[Observation] as o, FocalAreas.dbo.Count as c, FocalAreas.dbo.MonitoringPoint as mp
    WHERE EXISTS
      (Select 
          Count(o.ObservationID) as birds
          ,o.CountID
          ,mp.MonitoringPointID
              FROM [FocalAreas].[dbo].[Observation] as o, FocalAreas.dbo.Count as c, FocalAreas.dbo.MonitoringPoint as mp
              where o.CountID = c.CountID
              and c.MonitoringPointID = mp.MonitoringPointID
              and StateID = 'NE'
              and AOUSpeciesID = 1
              and Route = 'Focal'
              and datepart(year, CountDate) = 2014
              group by o.CountID, mp.MonitoringPointID)
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the processing are really useful.  The aggregation in your subquery is superfluous.

Comment: Sample input???  Expected output???  Table structure/relationship???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess, because your question could do with some closer description, but maybe you want to do the following:

```
SELECT
  avg(birds)
FROM (Select 
      Count(o.ObservationID) as birds
      ,o.CountID
      ,mp.MonitoringPointID
      FROM [FocalAreas].[dbo].[Observation] as o, FocalAreas.dbo.Count as c, FocalAreas.dbo.MonitoringPoint as mp
      where o.CountID = c.CountID
          and c.MonitoringPointID = mp.MonitoringPointID
          and StateID = 'NE'
          and AOUSpeciesID = 1
          and Route = 'Focal'
          and datepart(year, CountDate) = 2014
      group by o.CountID, mp.MonitoringPointID) as subq
```